# Do MacBook Pros have support for the Remote Control?

Tags: macbook-pro, remote-control, compatibility

Do the new (2011) [MacBook Pros](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro) work with Apple's [Remote Control](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC377LL/A)?

I'm little confused because the Apple Store offers me an Apple Remote when I try buying a new MacBook Pro, but I don't see any information about support for that remote in the MacBook Pro's description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Manual for the 13inch](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/MacBook_Pro_13inch_Early2011.pdf), here is a picture that shows you where the IR port is located.

[image: Basic Features of MacBook Pro]

Comment: This is a proof, which I want! thx

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does support it. You can verify this information because when you go to the apple store and select a new model, one of the accesories you can add to your purchase is the apple remote. They wouldn't add that if you couldn't use it :)

I assume the IrDA port is there @ the front of the machine, possible hard to see in the official pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. If you have the dock which supports it try not to put them close as it's the closest IR connection to you that picks it up!